# Why is this react route throwing an error of no route matched location?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-component

I have some problem related to routing in my code im getting error "react_devtools_backend.js:4026 No routes matched location "/airlines/1/reviews/new"  .That is when im trying to give a review to a particular airline.
here is my code
I have App.js-Airlines.js-AirlineCard.js-Reviews.js-AddReviewForm

App.js.My route is defined here

````
 const[reviews,setReviews]=useState([]); 
.
.
.

            <Routes>

          <Route exact  path="/airlines" element={<><Search search={search} onSearchChange={setSearch} /><Airlines  /></>} />
           
          <Route exact  path="/myprofile" element={<MyProfile />} />
          
       
          <Route exact  path="/airlines/:id" element={<Reviews reviews={reviews} setReviews={setReviews} />} />
           
          <Route path="/airlines/${id}/reviews/new" element={ <AddreviewForm />} />
        
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home user={user}/>} />
        
        </Routes>
```[enter image description here][1]

Airlines.js
````

function Airlines(){
const[airlines,setAirlines]=useState([]);

```
useEffect(()=>{
    fetch("/airlines")
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(airData=>{
      setAirlines(airData)
    })
  
   },[])
  

   
return(
    <>
    <h1>Airlines</h1>
   {airlines.map((airline)=>(
    <AirlinesCard key={airline.id} airline={airline}/>
   ))

   }
   
    </>
)
```

}

```
AirlineCard.js
```

function AirlinesCard({airline}){
const{id,name,image,slogan,wlink}=airline;
return(
<>

### {name}

##### {slogan}

<Link to={`/airlines/${id}`}>Enter

#### Book your tickets now!

```
    </>
)
```

}

```
Reviews.js
```

function Reviews({reviews,setReviews}){

useEffect(()=>{
fetch("/reviews")
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(reviewData=>{
setReviews(reviewData)
})
},[])

function handleAddReviews(newReview){
console.log("in handle add review", newReview)
setReviews([...reviews,newReview]);

}

```
const {id}=useParams();

console.log(reviews)
 let filteredReviews=reviews.filter(review=>{

  
   return review.airline.id===parseInt(id)})
return(
    <>
    <h1>Reviews</h1>
   
    <Link  to="/airlines"><button>Go Back</button></Link>
    <Link to={`/airlines/${id}/reviews/new`}><button>Add a Review</button></Link>
    { filteredReviews.map((review)=>{
```

return (

);
})}

```
    </>
)
```

}

```
I have defined my link to go to add review form in the Reviews.js

thanks

here is the link
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6JMJ.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route looks like it's got a typo, should be

```
<Route path="/airlines/:id/reviews/new" element={ <AddreviewForm />} />
```

instead of

```
<Route path="/airlines/${id}/reviews/new" element={ <AddreviewForm />} />
```

Comment: it was soo simple.Thank you soo much for your help :)